# Add a condition to a modal push segue

Tags: ios, swift

I use a navigation controller and modal show segues.
I want to block the back button of my second view controller if [condition] isn't true, for exemple by adding an alert "You can't go back until [condition]" when the user press the back button.

Don't know if it's possible, if someone know how to solve it !

Thanksss

Comment: Do some research on `shouldPerformSegue`.

Comment: I don't find anything that solve my problem :/

Comment: I don't find how to set the identifier segue in the shouldPerformSegue function

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a custom action for your back bar button item.

```
@IBAction func backPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
     if !myCondition {
          let alert = UIAlertViewController(title: "Alert", message: "Please fulfill the condition")
          let action = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", .default)
          self.present(alert, animated: true)
          return
     }
     navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

Or you can just use normal target action from code.

```
myBarButton.addTarget(self, selector: #selector(backButtonPressed(_:)))
```

Sorry for incorrect syntax.

Comment: Where do you drag the @IBAction in the soryboard ? I can't join it to the back button because it's not a real UIButton

Comment: If you're adding back button using storyboard then then right click on your controller and drag link from your function in the list to your bar button. Else if you have added button from code just go with the second method above in answer.

Comment: I did'nt add any button because I'm using a navigation view controller, so it automatically create a back button in a tab bar :)

Comment: then you can access the default one I guess like this.. `if let backButton = navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem {}`

Comment: Nope.. there isn't the .leftBackButtonItem {}

Answer (score 1):

Need back button image "ic-menu-back-primary"

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Nav Back Button
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ic-menu-back-primary"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(back(_:)))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
}


@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any?) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "You can't go back until [condition]", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let resume = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel)
    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Exit", style: .default) { (action) in
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    }

    alert.addAction(resume)
    alert.addAction(cancel)

    present(alert, animated: true)
}
```